# ATI Catalyst Control Center gives error (Radeon HD 6470M)

Tags: ati

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Radeon HD 6xxx cards [are not currently supported](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu#Unsupported_adapter). To avoid a wrong purchase (like I did) be aware of this. Also read [Switchable_Graphic_Chips_Warning](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Features#Switchable_Graphic_Chips_Warning).

The issue is summarized in the subject of this post, when on my laptop I click System > Preferences ATI Catalyst Control Center I get this message:

```
Initialization error:

There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.
It could be caused by the following.

No ATI graphics driver is installed, or the ATI driver is not functioning
properly. Please install the ATI driver appropriate for you ATI hardware,
or configure using aticonfig.
```

Some detail about environment:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]:
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics 
Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]:
ATI Technologies Inc NI Seymour [AMD Radeon HD 6470M] [1002:6760]
```

Installed packages:

```
ii  fglrx                     2:8.840-0ubuntu4
ii  fglrx-amdcccle            2:8.840-0ubuntu4
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon 1:6.14.0-0ubuntu4
```

I have installed ATI proprietary driver using "Additional Drivers" and Jockey says that the driver is activated and currently in use. After driver installation I'm able to use a resolution of 1366x768. I'm using classic interface (no Unity).

Additional info/oddities:

```
$ glxgears 
Segmentation fault
```

Hardware excerpts:

```
description: Notebook
product: HP Pavilion dv6 dv6-6008el Notebook PC
width: 64 bits
cpu: 4 x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
```

Please, let me know if I can provide further details to solve the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx
```

then for newest ati driver:

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-5-x86.x86_64.run
```

***If you have a 64 bit system, then install this before anything:***

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Once dowloaded right-click the .run file and set it to run as executable.

then.

```
cd /path_of_the_file
```

***This is for 32 bit only:***

```
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-5-x86.x86_64.run
```

***This is for 64 bit only:***

```
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-5-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/natty

sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Once it's done.

```
  sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

that's all you have to do.

Alternatively you can add this ppa.

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Comment: Many thanks, I'm going to try. Just one question: doing the manual installation, will the update manager automatically keep the driver up to date?

Comment: nope, once catalyst 11.6 comes out you will have to do it all over again, the PPA at the bottom of my answer automatically updates the catalyst packages however they aren't the latest ones , i think they're one version behind.

Comment: but I should be able to stay with 11.5 forever, isn't it?

Comment: for now, yes, then again until 11.6 comes out.

Comment: @Uri instead of posting the same answer over again instead flag this question to be closed by a duplicate of the previous qusetion

Comment: I followed your guide with care and did a reboot, but unluckily the issue is still present. `aticonfig` command output: `No supported adapters detected`. Any further data I can provide to help?

Comment: Not your fault, I'm in this case: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu#Unsupported_adapter

Comment: does your laptop uses any sort of dual GPU techonlogy? , i see you have 2 graphics adapter listed.

Comment: if not, as stated here: Minimal Config create a file in here  /etc/X11/xorg.conf and in it type this --> http://pastebin.com/c7xWwVy6

Comment: you can also force the creation of the file.--> sudo aticonfig --input=/etc/X11/xorg.conf --tls=1

Comment: `sudo aticonfig --input=/etc/X11/xorg.conf --tls=1` gives `No supported adapters detected`, while editing the file manually makes the boot process stop with a black screen. I guess AMD **Radeon HD 6470M** is **NOT SUPPORTED** at all.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10624606&postcount=11 <-take a look at that

Comment: seems like you do have  a dual GPU laptop , which is why it probably doesn't detect the ATI card.